# Eclipse - Ctrl-space to produce "instanceof"

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, instanceof

In Netbeans, if I press <kbd>Ctrl-space</kbd> in one of these conditions:

- after a field + at least one space;
- or after a method which returns a value (not `void`);

Then NetBeans produces `instanceof`. Is there that feature, or how can I configure it in Eclipse?

Thanks  :-)

**Edited**

I'm sorry, it's a long time I haven't used NetBeans. But if I remember right, at least two above conditions are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware that this can be configured, except maybe creating your own text template (search for "templates" in the preferences).

For me, `if(` *field* `in`<kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> works.

And probably file a feature request.

Comment: Thank you. I go to _Java -> Editor -> Templates_, but can't find something related to `Ctrl+Space`. Could you please tell me more about `if(` _field_ `in` Ctrl+Space? Btw, could you please tell me how to make text looks like the button (as your `Ctrl+Space`)? :-)

Comment: Type `if( field in` + <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> and "in" is expanded to `instanceof`. As for templates: <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> is configured to consider all templates as possible expansions. Type `sysout`<kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> PS: Use the keyboard element: `<kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>`

Comment: I got it, not exactly the same, but very useful for me. Thank you :-)